# Export download packages in Aptitude

Tags: aptitude

I have badly damaged my Debian with some stupid stunt. I am now trying to fix it with a live CD, `mount`ing the system on HDD, and `chroot`ing into the system to fix it with aptitude.

I am able to fix my broken with aptitude, but the `chroot`ed system cannot connect to the network.

My idea would be to download the deb packages for aptitude from the live CD system with `apt-get download` and copy these into `/var/cache/apt/archives` for the `chroot`ed system to find.

How can I export all packages that need to be downloaded from aptitude?

**EDIT** on request: This was the stupid stunt:

I was converting a i386 installation to amd64 and during that course, both I was installing a lot of packages for amd64 and uninstalling those for i386 in one go. That led to some essential commands not available on the system any more and unconfigured amd64 packages.

I could mount the HDD from the live CD, unpacking files with `ar x package_amd64.deb`, and `tar -xf data.tar.xz`, and copying the resulting folders to the HDD to continue.

Comment: "I have badly damaged my Debian with some stupid stunt." Perhaps some details on what you did would help?

Comment: A live CD : No packages at all. A live CD is a compressed image of an installed OS. What you need is "a Debian DVD" https://www.debian.org/distrib/

Comment: @KnudLarsen With the live CD I can download packages from the internet, before mounting the HDD to chroot into it, I need to install packages for mounting the encrypted volume.